# Python numpy - removing points from axis x in graph

Tags: python, numpy

I have this code:

```
import numpy as np
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import ipywidgets as widgets
from maux import init_subplot, smart_ticklabel
from mtest import true_false_test
plt.rcParams.update({'figure.max_open_warning': 0})


X = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi, 2*4*100+1)

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, sharex=True, sharey=True)
fig.set_size_inches(9, 10)

init_subplot(ax1)

xtick_numerators = range(-6, 6+1)
ax1.set_xticks([n * np.pi / 6 for n in xtick_numerators])
ax1.set_xticklabels([smart_ticklabel(n, r"\pi", 6)  for n in xtick_numerators])

ax1.set_ylim(-3.4, 4.4)

def df(X): return ((2 * np.sin(2*X)*np.cos(2*X)) / np.abs(np.sin(2*X))) +1 
dX = X 

ax1.plot(dX, df(dX), label="derivation")

fig.show()
```

and the problem is that in graph there are lines which shouldn't be there on axis x  - e.g. on points -2/π; 0; π/2. I don't know how to remove them. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: smart_ticklabel is also not defined.  Its impossible to get the full picture without including the code for these things.  Commenting line 6 in your code and defining a simple `smart_ticklabel` function doesn't seem to show anything unexpected

Comment: @ZaccharieRamzi This code has been edited since I commented wonder if I should delete my comment as it's no longer valid

Comment: I edited the code. Hope it works now for you.

Comment: @dfps12 what are `maux` and `mtest`?

Comment: make sure to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to understand how to write the perfect minimal working example.

Comment: You ask to have ticks at π/6, so it's at ... 0, π/6, 2π/6, 3π/6 and your function  `smart_ticklabel` renders 3π/6 as π/2.  Case closed.